# Jquery modal window called from tooltip link not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, modal-dialog

I have a javascript tooltip that I'd like to call a jquery modal window (by colorbox) when the link is clicked from within the tooltip. Each link has `class="modalPageWide"` assigned to it. The class modalPageWide is what calls the jquery modal window.

The problem is when any of the links within Example 1 is assigned modalPageWide and clicked, it does not call the jquery modal window. Can someone solve what I need to do for my final piece?

Here is a demo and my code: http://jsbin.com/ijeku4/4/

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
   {$(".modalPageWide").colorbox({
        width:"800px",height:"610px",opacity:0.6,iframe:true
   })}
);
```

Tooltip Code:

```
dw_Tooltip.defaultProps = {
      sticky: true,
  klass: 'tooltip',
  showCloseBox: true,
  klass: 'tooltip2', // class to be used for tooltips
      closeBoxImage: 'http://www.google.com/apps/images/x.png',
      wrapFn: dw_Tooltip.wrapSticky
}

dw_Tooltip.content_vars = {

tooltip_popup: {
        content: 'Click a link to continue' +
'<ul><li><a href="http://www.amazon.com" class="modalPageWide">Link 1</a></li>' +
'<li><a href="http://www.amazon.com" class="modalPageWide">Link 2</a></li>' +
'<li><a href="http://www.amazon.com" class="modalPageWide">Link 3</a></li>' +
'<li><a href="http://www.amazon.com" class="modalPageWide">Link 4</a></li></ul>',
        klass: 'tip'
    }
}
```

Comment: On your example page, the link that supposedly opens a modal window instead just sends me to Amazon. There are errors reported by Chrome; it looks like the "https" links to your scripts may be causing problems.

Comment: @Pointy - When I click Example 2, it should open in a modal window. Example 1 is the one that I want to open in a modal window when the links from within the tooltip is clicked. Video Example of what happens when I click
http://www.screencast.com/users/evanmoore/folders/Jing/media/8dd312f2-5846-4431-8a6a-84dc6077f6ae

Comment: Yes, I know @Evan, but the whole thing just does not work because that "dl_web" site returns 403 errors and will not hand over the JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: @Pointy - darn. it must be cuz i'm signed in. i'll fix.

Comment: @pointy - i updated the source files. sorry about that. i was signed into my account, but then no one could see my source.

Comment: I think it can be made to work by setting up an "on_show" function - see my edited answer.

Comment: @pointy - again, thank you. i credited for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that your initialization code cannot affect the tooltip contents because they're not in the DOM at the time the initialization happens. They're only added when the tooltip is shown. I don't know what tooltip plugin that is, but if there's a way to add a callback to it that is invoked when the tooltip is shown, then you could put your initialization code in there.

*edit* — OK now that I can see that tooltip plugin, it looks like you can give it an "on_show" function in the options:

```
dw_Tooltip.defaultProps = {
  sticky: true,
  klass: 'tooltip',
  showCloseBox: true,
  klass: 'tooltip2', // class to be used for tooltips
  closeBoxImage: 'http://www.google.com/apps/images/x.png',
  wrapFn: dw_Tooltip.wrapSticky

};

dw_Tooltip.on_show = function() {
   $(".modalPageWide").colorbox({
      width:"800px",height:"610px",opacity:0.6,iframe:true
   })
};
```

This may need to be tweaked, depending on how that tooltip thing works. (I looked it over but I didn't thoroughly walk through it all.)  If the tooltip contents are re-added to the DOM on each activation, then this will probably be OK; if, however, the tooltip sticks around, and depending on what "colorbox" does, it may be necessary to keep track of whether the tooltip DOM fragment has already been "colorboxed".

Comment: thank you very very much. you solved it. here's the demo where it works http://jsbin.com/ijeku4/9/

Comment: i have a follow up question. instead of "hover", which is how the tooltip is being activated, do you know if a click could activate the tooltip? http://jsbin.com/ijeku4/9/

Comment: Well I'm not very familiar with how that plugin works - however, that really would be a fine thing to ask as a separate question on its own. Somebody else might know!

Comment: good advice. I did just that. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008226/activate-tooltip-using-onclick-jquery